# Select elements from a list

Tags: r, list, select

```
a <- list(One = "a", Two = 1, Three= c (4, 5, 6))
```

How to pick up 1st and 3rd elements in this list?
Tried

```
[[1, 3]]
a[[1, 3]]
x(a[["One"],["Three"]])
x(a[["One","Three"]])
```

and other variants...

Comment: @markus Since this is about accessing multiple elements (essentially subsetting the list) instead of one (extracting from the list), I think it's not a dupe / your answer is independently useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can subset by position

```
a[c(1, 3)]
#$One
#[1] "a"

#$Three
#[1] 4 5 6
```

If we deal with a named list, we can also subset by name

```
a[c("One", "Three")]
```